# Al compilar mi proyecto con maven me arroja un error

Tags: java

> Caused by: javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to create a
>   Configuration, because no Bean Validation provider could be found. Add
>   a provider like Hibernate Validator (RI) to your classpath.   at
>   javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:271)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.validation.MessageInterpolatorFactory.getObject(MessageInterpolatorFactory.java:53)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor$ValidatedLocalValidatorFactoryBean.(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:413)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.getValidator(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:370)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.determineValidator(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:354)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:316)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:292)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1626)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1181)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1075)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:220)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1018)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:345)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:340)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization(DataSourceInitializerPostProcessor.java:62)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:423)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1638)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.obtainBeanInstanceFromFactory(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:389)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:361)
>     at
>   com.platzi.profesoresplatzi.configuration.DataBaseConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$71cae749.dataSource()
>     at
>   com.platzi.profesoresplatzi.configuration.DataBaseConfiguration.sessionFactory(DataBaseConfiguration.java:22)
>     at
>   com.platzi.profesoresplatzi.configuration.DataBaseConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$71cae749.CGLIB$sessionFactory$0()
>     at
>   com.platzi.profesoresplatzi.configuration.DataBaseConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$71cae749$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$6e387bfa.invoke()
>     at
>   org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358)
>     at
>   com.platzi.profesoresplatzi.configuration.DataBaseConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$71cae749.sessionFactory()
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1181)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1075)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:742)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:121)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:189)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:131)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)  at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)  at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:283)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:173)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:128)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
>
> Results :
>
> Tests in error:    ProfesoresPlatziApplicationTests.contextLoads »
>   IllegalState Failed to load Ap...
>
> Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0
>
> [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD FAILURE [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time: 26.081 s [INFO] Finished at:
>   2018-08-14T00:33:02-05:00 [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [WARNING] The requested profile "pom.xml" could not be activated
>   because it does not exist. [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test
>   (default-test) on project profesoresplatzi: There are test failures.
>   [ERROR]  [ERROR] Please refer to
>   D:\CursosPlatziMarioRamonUceda\JavaEE\IdeSpring Tool Suite
>   Bueno\Work-space STS Bueno\ProfesoresPlatzi\target\surefire-reports
>   for the individual test results. [ERROR] -> [Help 1] [ERROR]  [ERROR]
>   To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e
>   switch. [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug
>   logging. [ERROR]  [ERROR] For more information about the errors and
>   possible solutions, please read the following articles: [ERROR] [Help
>   1]
>   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException

Comment: Por favor agrega el archivo pom.xml a la pregunta

Comment: Ya lo solucioné Rcordoval, lo que hice fue sustituir la anotación @SpringBootApplication por @SpringBootApplication(exclude = {JndiConnectionFactoryAutoConfiguration.class,DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
        HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class,JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class,DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class}).
La solución la vi :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49197104/10214389

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es probable que necesites la dependencia de Hibernate Validator.

Agrega lo siguiente al pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

**Además**:

Spring boot tiene clases de AutoConfiguración habilitadas por defecto para los data sources que ya existen en el classpath. hay que excluirlos explícitamente de la siguiente manera:

Sustituir la anotación @SpringBootApplication por:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {JndiConnectionFactoryAutoConfiguration.class,DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
        HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class,JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class,DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class})

@ComponentScan
public class MyBootApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyBootApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ya agregue las dependencias en el pom.xml pero me arroja lo siguiente, ya busque, volví hacer el proyecto ya no sé que hacer:
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least one JPA metamodel must be present!



No es todo el error es una parte pero eso me sale @Rcordoval, ¿alguna otra opción que sepas?

Comment: Podrias agregar el archivo JavaConfig o configuracion XML?

Comment: Ya lo solucioné Rcordoval, lo que hice fue sustituir la anotación @SpringBootApplication por @SpringBootApplication(exclude = {JndiConnectionFactoryAutoConfiguration.class,DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class,JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class,DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class}). La solución la vi : stackoverflow.com/a/49197104/10214389

Comment: Si esta respuesta ayudo a resolver tu problema, puedes marcarla como [aceptada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) dando click en el icono de `aceptar(check)` que aparece al lado izquierdo de la respuesta que elijas. Toma en cuenta que esta es una comunidad de programadores y en el futuro podría ser de gran ayuda.